# Regexp replace all symbols excluding # and @

Tags: regex, go, text, replace

I am not super confident with using regexp, but my end goal is to have something that is removing all symbols excluding `@` and `#`.

What I have now is **`[\\p{P}\\d]`**.
It works fine but it also removes `@` and `#` which I need to keep.

Here is the sample input string:

```
^Hello, my #friend @Даниил%% 中英 字 典!!.
```

that I am trying to change into

```
Hello my #friend @Даниил 中英 字 典
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the symbols you need to keep and replace with `$1` backreference to restore the captured part in the resulting string:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    s := "^Hello, my #friend @Даниил%% 中英 字 典!!."
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`([#@])|[\p{P}\p{S}\d]`)
    s = re.ReplaceAllString(s, "$1")
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

See [this Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/LLUEtpmUby) printing `Hello my #friend @Даниил 中英 字 典`.

Note that `^` does not belong to the `\p{P}`  category, thus, I added `\p{S}` one.

The pattern is `([#@])|[\p{P}\p{S}\d]`, see [its online demo](https://regex101.com/r/VQ2ZZh/1).

**Details**:

- `([#@])` - Capturing group 1 (referred to with `$1` / `${1}` from the replacement pattern) matching a `#` or `@`
- `|` - or
- `[\p{P}\p{S}\d]` - a punctuation, symbol or digit char.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.